# difference between unconditionally sure, perfect confidentiality, and semantically sure, adversary-wise and advatnage-wise?

Tags: perfect-secrecy, semantic-security

can anyone please tell me the difference between unconditionally secure, perfect confidentiality and  semantically secure? I know that for perfect confidentiality, we have an adversary A that has an  advantage that equals to 0,`Pr(w0) = Pr(w1)`, while the adversary has unlimited resources, and for semantically secure the advantage is equal to 0 but with a negligible epsilon , and i think unconditionally secure means the same thing as semantically secure but the adversary has limited resources?  please let me know of the correct difference, thank you.
in the lecture provided by the professor, they are the following definitions:

> The concept of perfect privacy is based on the assumption that an attacker observes a unique ciphertext that matches a unique encryption key. We are talking about single-use keys. Nevertheless, we will grant the opponent unlimited computing power.
> We will have perfect confidentiality if the opponent (A) fails and succeeds in this game with exactly the same probability, that is to say, $\Pr (W_0) = \Pr (W_1)$.
> If so, $A$'s advantage in this game is $AvCP (A, E) = 0$.
> We see that it is zero against an unconditionally secure encryption system, even when $A$ has a unlimited amount of resources and unlimited computing time.

and the definition of semantically secure:

[image]

where `AVss` is the advantage of the opponent (which is an efficient opponent meaning the resources are LIMITED)
he also said that:

> unconditional security where the adversary would be endowed with infinite computing power.

but at the same time he mentioned that unconditionally secure is equal to semantically secure :

> An unconditionally secure encryption system is semantically secure.
> Indeed, we have seen that the advantage to an adversary (effective or not) against such encryption is zero.
> The disposable mask is a concrete example of an encryption system semantically safe (since unconditionally safe).

so I'm very confused since he said previously that in semantically secure the resources are limited, but in unconditionally secure they aren't limited, yet he said that unconditionally secure is equal to semantically secure??

Comment: Well, the answer may be too long to write. A simple one; we relax from the perfect security since it requires key size equal to message size and must not be reused. In the semantical security, we relax the condition about the adversary has power polynomially bounded. Semantical Security can be shown to equal Ind-CPA and easier to prove things. So **where did you take the definitions that you confused**? Could you indicate this?

Comment: @kelalaka thank you for the reply, and I took them from my lessons, provided by the professor, he told us to differentiate between them just in that, depending on advantage, limited/unlimited recourses , because in lesson it says that unconditionally secure is semantically secure but at the same time there is a difference because I guess semantically secure isn't unconditionally sure, there isn't an equivalence between them

Comment: SO, this is HW. You may [edit] your question with the definitions from the lecture and we can provide you some guidance with comments.

Comment: @kelalaka I've edited it with definitions from lecture

Comment: $$\text{unconditionally secure encryption} \implies   \text{semantically secure}$$ but the converse is not true. You are missing this point. $$\text{semantically secure} \nRightarrow   \text{unconditionally secure encryption}$$

Comment: @kelalaka oh I got that thank you, but does perfect confidentiality equal to any of them? because I believe he said at some point that it's equal to semantically secure

Comment: Not clear, however, it should be  `unconditionally sure = perfect confidentiality` you may consider the Lindell&Katz as side book...

Comment: @kelalaka so unconditionally sure = perfect confidentiality and unconditionally sure=semantically secure , but semantically secure isn't unconditionally sure and it isn't perfect confidentiality, okay thank you very much for your time, sorry I asked  a lot ^^

Comment: You are using `=` instead of `=>` here `unconditionally sure => semantically secure`

Comment: @kelalaka  unconditionally sure => semantically secure and 'unconditionally sure = perfect confidentiality' one of them equals and the other only equals in one way

Comment: Yes, you can see that from the $\epsilon$

Comment: @kelalaka thanks lots!